# onListItemClick returns data from the item at the top of current view

Tags: android, listview

I have a onListItemClick that returns the text from item in the listview with:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_title);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (tv).getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The problem is the data it returns is from the item at the top of the current listview no the actual list item that is clicked. To illustrate if I had a list that was like this

```
A
----- (Start of Viewable area)
B
C
D
------(End of viewable area)
E
```

If I click on item D the toast will return the Title for item B. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: can't you use something like `l.getItemAtPosition(position))`?

Comment: What type of data your list has? Strings or textview?

Comment: Did you try this? TextView tView=(TextView)getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is being called from within your custom ListView, correct?  From what I can tell, "findViewById" is searching the entire ListView for a view with the id "R.id.item_title".  Since you have multiple list items on the screen, it's pulling the top one.  Instead, call

```
// Call on the child view provided as a parameter, instead of on the ListView
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
```

so that it searches child views of the View object passed as parameter "v".